# Linux: USB-trigger on connect only fires on first connect. Requires `systemd --user damon-reload` to be active again

Tags: linux, usb, systemd

**The problem:**

I have a tablet w. stylus. I'd like the tablet to undergo some configuration whenever I connect it via USB. I'm almost there, my config-script is registered with systemctl as a *oneshot* service and that service is triggered the first time I connect the tablet.  However the service is not triggered on subsequent connects: in other words, if I disconnect the tablet and reconnect it, the trigger is not fired. I have to do a `systemctl --user daemon-reload` before the trigger becomes active again. What am I missing?

**System:**
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.4.0-52-lowlatency

**Here is my trigger:**

filename: `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-wacom.rules`

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", 
ATTR{idVendor}=="256c", 
ATTR{idProduct}=="006d", 
MODE="0666", 
TAG+="systemd", 
ENV{SYSTEMD_USER_WANTS}="tablet-conf.service"
```

*(there are no linebreaks in the actual file, I just put them in for easier reading)*

**Here is my service-definition:**

filename: `~/.config/systemd/user/tablet-conf.service`

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/huion-inspiroy-950d-connect.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=xsession.target
```

**Here's my configuration-script**:

Filename: `~/bin/system/devices/huion-inspiroy-950d-connect.sh`
Called via a symlink `/usr/local/bin/huion-inspiroy-950d-connect.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-connected-waiting
sleep 2
touch /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-connected-waited
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d stylus" MapToOutput HEAD-0 2>> /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-configured
xsetwacom set "HID 256c:006d stylus" rotate HALF 2>> /home/esm/bin/system/devices/a-configured
```

*(as you can see, I create some empty files and log som info during the configuration. All this is of course not necessary, but I needed it, when I was figuring out how to get the trigger working. I'll remove it, once I've figured out how to get the whole thing to behave)*

**So the question is ...**

How can I achieve that the trigger is fired on every tablet-connection, and not just the first?